# Excecute sh script from crontab using docker

Tags: docker, cron

I want to excecute a .sh script every minute via cronjob using a crontab in a docker container. It also serves an apache webserver. 
The Dockerfile is looking like this (I kept the important parts inside):

```
#start with base Image from php 
FROM php:7.3-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  cron

#Update crontab
RUN   echo "*   *   *   *   *   root    /var/etc/jobs/cron.sh" > /etc/crontab

#Restart Crontab and start apache then
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "service cron restart && apache2-foreground"]

EXPOSE 80
```

The cron.sh file is in /var/etc/jobs/cron.sh . I need to call the env Variable $CRON_MAIL why I put it into a .sh file. The file is looking like

```
#Do E-Mail Sync
if [ -z "$CRON_MAIL" ]
then
  echo "Cron Mail nicht eingerichtet"
else
  curl $CRON_MAIL
fi
```

While $CRON_MAIL is a specific URL that should be called every minute. When I call the script manually, it is running fine. So I assume that this is correct.

However, the cronjob itself does not call it. I am also not sure if it is running at all. I was trying to change the user from root to www-data and I also tried out **sh /var/etc/jobs/cron.sh** but it is not working. What can I do to let the .sh file run every minute?

Comment: you are not copying ` /var/etc/jobs/cron.sh` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: is the cron.sh starting with #!/bin/bash or similar? Could you have output of the cron.sh redirected to a file?

Comment: @Andrea: No, it is written like above. Does it make a difference? I am not that aware in this.

Comment: @Adiii: I have not inserted the copying above because it was done through a volume mapping at the moment for testing. But this file exists and can be executed.

Comment: I inserted now #!/bin/bash to the top of the sh file but it is still not working. I also added this to the top of the crontab and added an empty line at the buttom of the file but it is not calling the sh file.

Comment: What happens if you run it manually ?

Comment: If I call it manually, it is working. I guess it has some problems, that I am using the Environment Variable.